# php conditional strpos check cant set session variable

Tags: php, forms, session, post, strpos

Please explain why I cannot get the session variable for "Pistol" to set or $_SESSION['reported'], but it works fine for "Rifle"

**THE FORM THAT POSTS THE DATA**

```
<form name="<?=$prodadd?>" id="<?=$prodadd?>" method="post" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="formid" value="addtocart" />
<!-- other input fields here -->
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="<?=$row['Type']?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="weight" value="<?=$row['Weight']?>" />
<!-- other input fields here --> 
</form>
```

**THE SIMPLE CHECK IN process.php TO SET THE SESSION VARIABLE:**

```
if (strpos($_POST[type],"Pistol")) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['pwght'] = $_SESSION['pwght'] + $_POST['weight'];
session_write_close();}

else if (strpos($_POST[type],"Rifle")) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['rwght'] = $_SESSION['rwght'] + $_POST['weight'];
session_write_close();}

$_SESSION['reported'] = $_POST['weight'];
```

**WHAT I HAVE DONE AND TRIED:**

I have looked in the Database after both a Rifle item and a Pistol item was sent through the form. Other than normal product differences they are the same. I have checked and verified that in both cases the data is being written to the database and is not blank or missing. I have changed the order of in which the if/else if is performed with same results. I have changed the name of the session names with no change in problem. No matter what I do I cannot get it to set the $_SESSION['pwght'] or $_SESSION['reported']

Comment: What happens if you alter all those `if(strpos($_POST[type],"string"))`'s into `if(strpos($_POST[type],"string")!==false)`'s? (Note: unless `type` is a defined constant, you probably should be using `$_POST['type']`, although that is not the issue here.

Comment: @Wrikken well, that seems to have fixed it but i do not know why. (As a side note I had it as `$_POST['xxx']` before with no change, i just recently took single quotes out as an attempt to try anything to fix it.) -- Can you explain why using a true/False check works but the other method doesn't?

Comment: If you look at the manual for [`strpos`](http://www.php.net/strpos), there's a big red box explaining why, and it helps to know about [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php): the position of the substring in the string is returned, if the position is at _the very first character_, that position is `0`. A bare `0` evaluates to false. So, there's a difference between strpos() output being `0` or `false`. The type-safe comparisons (`===` & `!==`) do not only compare 'truthy' or 'falsy' values, but check whether the left & right expressions are the same _type_.

Comment: @Wrikken got it - Please write a ANSWER based on above and I will vote up/ accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the manual for strpos](http://www.php.net/strpos)

> **Warning**
>
> This function may return *Boolean* **FALSE**, but may also return a *non-Boolean* value which evaluates to **FALSE**. Please read the [section on Booleans](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) for more information. Use [the === operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for testing the return value of this function.

In other words, you want to check whether it returns the *boolean* **false**, but not anything else that would [*evaluate* to false when cast to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) (in this case `0`, it matches at the very first character). This is done by:

```
if(strpos($haystack,$needle)!==false)
```